# Server based database with Onsen/Monaca

Tags: database, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui, monaca

I'm looking for advice if it is possible to use server based database with the onsen/monaca framework? I know Monaca has its own backend database that can be utilized; however, I intend to not have my project's database cloud based.

Initially, I would have used mysql or mongodb if I was working with Php/javascript, but given I want to make hybrid phone app using onsen/monaca, I don't know if I can go the same route. I'm new to onsen, and I am still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Onsen is simply a UI framework or in short, a very fancy collection of html, css, and JS. It is compatible with any database you use. You would need to utilize JS to connect to some server-side language like PHP or use Node.JS that would actually connect to your remote database. Hope that helps!

Local databases, on the other hand, have to do with the target device and phonegap than Onsen. The most common plugins support SQLite.